# Springboot Mapping and DTO

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to Spring and I'm encountering a lot of doubts when making an insertion of the example below.
I currently have three tables whose models are those below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "namespace")
public class Namespace {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String namespacename;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "services")
public class Services {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String servicename;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "historiquedeploiement")
public class HistoriqueDeploiement {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;    

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idnamespace", nullable = false)    
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
    @JsonProperty("idnamespace")
    private Namespace namespace;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idservices", nullable = false)    
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
    @JsonProperty("idservices")
    private Services services;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String tagvalue;
}
```

And this is my DTO :

```
public class HistoriqueDeploiementReadingDTO {
        @NotNull
        private Integer id;

        @NotNull
        private String namespacename;

        @NotNull
        private String servicename;
        
        @NotNull
        private String tagvalue;

}
```

So the problem is :
I receive an object of type HistoriqueDeploiementReadingDTO and i have to insert it in historiquedeploiement table.
The problem is that i receive "namespacename", "servicename" and i need to save the id of each one that i can find in the table namespace and service.

When i have the id of each one, i can save it in historiquedeploiement table.

I hope you understand that little problem and hope you can purpose me something :)
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first validate what you receive(against db records of each table). More or less the following will give you a highlight, so you should do for the others too.
**Don't forget that all should be on the same transaction.**

*== updated==*

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class) 
public boolean saveHistoriqueDeploiement(HistoriqueDeploiementReadingDTO  dto) {
    Services service = getServices(dto.getServicename());
    // do the same for the others

    HistoriqueDeploiement deploiment = new HistoriqueDeploiement();
    deploiment.setService(service);
    //same for the others

    deploiementRepository.save(deploiment);
}

public Services getServices(String serviceName) {
    Services service = serviceRepository.findByServicename(serviceName); //if it exists, use the existing

    if(service == null) {
        service = new Services();
        service.setServicename(dto.getServicename());
        service = serviceRepository.save(service);
    }
    
    return service;
}
```

Comment: There is something that bothers me, at no time we don't talk about the id of the service/namespace table, you use deploiment.setService(service), can you explain me why?

Comment: hibernate it self will handle that for you.

Comment: Ok thanks ! That's beautiful :) 
I will validate your answer, just to be sure, i putted ManyToOne annotation on historiquedeploiement. Should i put OneToMany on Service/Namespace ?

Comment: It depends on what your needs are. it is called *bidirectional many-to-one*. If you want to fetch `HistoriqueDeploiement` from `Services` or `Namespace` etc, *YES*. If you fetch all the others from `HistoriqueDeploiement`, *NO*. check here for a comprehensive explanation https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-map-bidirectional-many-one-association/

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 ways:

First of all

if relation is many to one your field is List of services and List of namespaces instead services and namespaces.

if you mean OneToOne

```
HistoriqueDeploiementReadingDTO historiqueDeploiementReadingDTO;

NameSpace nameSpace = new Namespace();
namespace.setNameSpaceName(historiqueDeploiementReadingDTO.getNameSpaceName());

Services service = new Service();
service.setServicename(historiqueDeploiementReadingDTO.getServiceName())

HistoriqueDeploiement historiqueDeploiement = new HistoriqueDeploiement;
historiqueDeploiement.setTagValue(historiqueDeploiementReadingDTO.getTagValue())
historiqueDeploiement.setService(service)
historiqueDeploiement.setNameSpaceName(nameSpace)

IHistoriqueDeploiementRepository.save(historiqueDeploiement);
```

2 -

Comment: A (service or namespace) can be specified in many "historiquedeploiement"

In historiqueDeploiement.setService(service) i don't see any "id" where is it ? 
I have to save the idservice and idnamespacename in historiqueDeploiement
Thanks

Comment: you can add theclass because you variable is not integer, ist a service/namespace class